# Iterating a javascript collection and adding a sort order

Tags: javascript

I have a tree in javascript which has multiple root elements and nested children.

Here's the object:

```
[{
  _id: '546d30905d7edd1d5169181d',
  name: 'first'
  children: []
}, {
  _id: '546d30905d7edd1d2169181d',
  name: 'second'
  children: []
}, {
  _id: '446d30905d7edd1d5169181d',
  name: 'third',
  children: [{
    _id: '446d30905d7e2d1d5169181d',
    name: '3child',
    children: []
  }, {
    _id: '446d30915d7e2d1d5169181d',
    name: '3child2',
    children: [{
      _id: '546d30905d7edd1d2569181d',
      name: 'second2',
      children: []
    }]
  }]
}, {
  _id: '546d30995d7edd1d5169181d',
  name: 'fourth',
  children: []
}]
```

This is a truncated document that's being stored in MongoDB using materialized path.  The issue is that I need to add a 'sorting' ability, so nodes in the same root can be sorted.

I want to iterate this tree and apply a `sort_value` such as `node['sort_value'] = 0`, etc.

Each level will have it's own sort order, starting at 0.

I can simply iterate the tree recursively:

```
function iterate(items) {
  _.each(items, function(page, key) {
    if (items.children.length > 0) {
      iterate(items.children);
    }
  });
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to keep track of the sort orders and also update the object's to include the sort_value field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I did it so that I used array key for sorting and "synchronized" it with object property (because I needed it saved to DB and restored after) and it works as a charm :)

So something like this, pseudo:

```
var unsorted = [
0:{"sort_key": "0", "data":"dataaa 0"},
1:{"sort_key": "1", "data":"dataaa 1"},
...
n:{"sort_key": "n", "data":"dataaa n"}
];


function_sort(unsorted){ 
    ...
    return sorted = [
      0:{"sort_key": "n", "data":"dataaa y"},
      1:{"sort_key": "44", "data":"dataaa x"},

      ...

      n:{"sort_key": "0", "data":"dataaa z"}
    ];
}



save = function_save(sorted){

...update sort_key as array key...
return for_saving;

}
```